# asp.net CustomValidator running when RegularExpressionValidator fails.

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Might be a dumb question, sorry if it is.

I have a field which I want the user to enter 9 digits.
I'm using a RegularExpressionValidator for that.
I also have a CustomValidator on that field to do some math parsing on the number if it passes the RegularExpressionValidator conditions.

However, if the user enters say 4 digits, the custom validator still fires.  Is there a way I can only make it fire if the first validator succeeds?  Yes I know I can prob combine it all into one custom validator but that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your code doesnt exist, i can only suggest you to try this.

```
if(ModelState["YourData"].Errors.Count > 0)
{
// the area for invoke your customvalidator  
YourCustomValidator.IsValid(){
}

}
else
{
// do something else.
}
```

And also please check your RegularExpressionValidator's string length.